# Why do I have keys of strangers in my GPG keychain?

Tags: pgp, digital-signature

I'm going though my GPG keychain. I've got a key for a few strangers in my keychain. I don't recall exchanging keys and I'm not sure how the public keys came to be installed in the keychain. I think (perhaps incorrectly) it may have been installed by GPG for Mac OS X, but I'm not certain.

I did find some references to him relating to Firefox, but I *do not* use a GPG/Firefox plugin, so the browser and the keychain should be disjoint.

What reasons could this have?

Comment: Do you read any newsgroups or follow any mailing lists?  It seems Vincent does and that he uses GPG when doing so.

Comment: @Ladadadada - yes, I spend most of my time on news groups and mailing lists. But I read through Firefox and Gmail, and the browser does not have the GPG plugin. That's why I am baffled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of mail clients will automatically fetch certificates if you receive signed mail (or news group postings) to be able to verify them. Especially newsgroup postings and messages on mailing lists can lead to a rather high number of "drive-by" certificate downloads.

Certificates of unknowns are not a problem at all: unless you trust them, they do not have any effect on validation of other keys unless trusted, but enable you to validate signatures (on files/messages) issued by this key if GnuPG can find a trust path to them.